# Jquery - 'Failed to load resource' - Problema al hacer peticion ajax POST

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, api

Tengo un pequeño problema. Estoy intentando realizar una peticion ajax POST, que simplemente es insertar unos datos en mi base de datos.

Tengo mi API REST creada con su metodo de insertar en la base de datos.
Esto funciona perfecto porque lo he verificado por Postman.

Despues, tengo mi front-end desarrollado en Visual Studio Code, en donde llamo al metodo de mi API mediante AJAX.

El problema esta en que cuando quiero hacer el envio de formulario, me aparce el siguiente error:

> The parameterized query '(@nombre nvarchar(4000),@apellidos nvarchar(4000),@documento int' expects the parameter '@nombre', which was not supplied.

La verdad es que no entiendo por que me sale este error.

Dejo mi código:

Metodo en API REST en C#:

```
public static bool InsertarDatos(datos datos)
{
    string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MiConexion"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    string query = "insert into TicketAtencionAlCliente(Nombre,Apellidos,Documento,Correo,MotivoLLamada,DesarrolloMotivo) values (@nombre,@apellidos,@documento,@correo,@motivo,@desarrollomotivo)";
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", datos.Nombre);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellidos", datos.Apellidos);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", datos.Documento);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", datos.Correo);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motivo", datos.MotivoLlamada);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desarrollomotivo", datos.DesarrolloMotivo);
    bool esta = false;

    try
    {
        conexion.Open();
        int filas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (filas > 0)
        {
            esta = true;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        conexion.Close();
    }

    return esta;
}
```

Funcion en Visual Studio Code (mi front-end que consume metodo de API)

```js
function GuardarTicket(Nombre, Apellidos, Documento, Correo, MotivoLlamada, DesarrolloMotivo) {
    var datos = {
        Nombre: Nombre,
        Apellidos: Apellidos,
        Documento: Documento,
        Correo: Correo,
        MotivoLlamada: MotivoLlamada,
        DesarrolloMotivo: DesarrolloMotivo
    }
    var dir = "GuardarTicket";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: api + dir,
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(inserto) {
            if (inserto == true) {
                alertMessage("Datos enviados satisfactoriamente.", "Aviso");
            } else {
                alertMessage("Ha ocurrido un error en el envio de datos, verifique si ha completado todos los campos...", "Aviso");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function Guardar() {
    var nombre = $("#txtNombre").val();
    var apellidos = $("#txtApellidos").val();
    var documento = $("#txtDocumento").val();
    var correo = $("#txtCorreo").val();
    var motivo = $("#slcMotivo").val();
    var desarrolloMotivo = $("#txtDesarrolloMotivo").val();

    GuardarTicket(nombre, apellidos, documento, correo, motivo, desarrolloMotivo);
}
```

Debuggeando desde consola los datos llegan bien.

[image: Mi código (JavaScript) en Visual Studio Code]

Gracias de antemano me tiene trancado hace rato esto.

Comment: en principio no noto ningun error en el codigo, si pones un breakpoint en `InsertarDatos()` puedes ver que el codigo se detiene y al ir paso a paso evaluas que los datos que llegan son los correctos? quizas esta ingresando a un lugar diferente, primero descarta que se ejecuta el codigo que piensas realmente se esta ejecutando cuando lo llamas desde ajax

Comment: Si, se ejecuta, lo puedo hacer debug desde consola, los datos llegan perfecto, voy a subir una imagen de la consola cuando llegan los datos asi lo puedes ver tmb.

Comment: pero en el codigo .net se detiene el breakpoint en InsertarDatos() ? no digo evaluar solo la consola desde el browser, evalua el codigo del lado del backend

Comment: la api rest que llamas esta implementada con asp.net mvc o es un aspx exponiendo un webmethod? porque en el codigo que nos muestras de esa api algo me esta faltando para exponerla completamente

Comment: Si llega! Pero llega si lo pruebo en POSTMAN por localhost... Porque mi API la tengo publicada en IIS y desde visual code trato de llegar con la direccion de IP! No se hacerlo de otra forma, como vos decis, de ejecutar el frontend y vaya al brackPoint del backend

Comment: Si esta implementada con asp.net mvc.. Si solamente subi el codigo que inserta a la BD, no subi lo que seria mi controlador que llama a ese metodo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Para mi el problema esta desde mi frontend, estoy descartando que sea de backend ya que por postman me funciona todo

Comment: lo implementas en mvc, pero entonces le defines en el action el [HttpPost] porque sino no va a ingresar, por defecto lo va a definir para el GET

Comment: Si obvio por supuesto, en mi controlador tengo [httpost] y por debajo un IHttpActionResult en el cual llamo al metodo InsertarDatos, y a lo que es bool.. si es True devuelvo OK!.. Por eso digo, para mi el problema esta en el frontend, ya que probando desde postman funciona tdo bien y me lo inserta en la base de datos

Comment: la prueba que tienes que hacer es ejecutar front y back asi pones un breakpoint en el codigo del back y pruebas invocandolo desde el browser directo

Comment: Bien, voy a probar, en ves de llamar a la ip, llamo al local host

Comment: @LeandroTuttini acabe de probar, y los datos me estan llegando todos en NULL

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no se que podria ser mi error, me dejo mas perdido todavia

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos un ejemplo

[Post The Data To ASP.NET MVC Controller Using JQuery Ajax](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/post-the-data-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax)

se observa que defines el `dataType` pero tambien el `contentType`

```
 $.ajax({  
       type: "POST",  
       url: "/JQueryAjaxCall/AjaxPostCall",  
       data: JSON.stringify(employee),  
       contentType: "application/json",  
       dataType: "json",
```

de esta forma el codigo backend podra interpretar los datos que recibe

Creo que el codigo de backend no aplica el binding no intepreta el tipo del dato que recibe

Comment: No me ha servido, ahora estoy probando por LocalHost como tu me habias dicho.. y al agregarle el contentType, no me lleva a depurar en c#, no se porqie